# Mongodb count all value with different key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any way in monogdb to group all value with different key. Below is my data structure:

[image: data structure]

So my question is **how can i count all `0/0` `0/1` occurrence times?** I have googled for a while and all answers i got with the same key. but you can see my keys inside samples are not the same. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4.

Use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to transform object to array of key value pairs followed by [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on value to count occurrences.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{"samples":{"$objectToArray":"$samples"}}},
  {"$unwind":"$samples"},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$samples.v","count":{"$sum":1}}}
])
```

Comment: thanks, but here i can not use objectToArray function, whether is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Np. I'm afraid there is not a way on server side. You have to do it client side. Can you change structure to store the values as array ? like samples:[{k:b56, v:0/1}, ....]